# JTextPane with HTML - local image won't load

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtextpane

I'm trying to load a local image into a JTextPane, and the program relentlessly displays a broken image icon. This is the HTML code:

```
    <img src="file:\\C:\farmostrich.gif" width=77 height=777"/>
```

The program instantiates the JTextPane and displays the other parts of the html file (e.g. text, hyperlinks), but no image.

```
textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setContentType("text/html");
textPane.setText(htmlString);
```

Any suggestions? Thank you all so much!

Comment: That HTML snippet is invalid (for any version of HTML).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do like this: adding image into src folder

```
textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setContentType("text/html");
String htmlString = "<html><body width=\"595\" height=\"842\">
   <div align=\"left\"><img src=\"" + this.getClass().getClassLoader()
   .getResource("images/logo_html.png").toString()+"\" /></div>.....";
textPane.setText(htmlString);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To be interpreted as HTML, the snippet needs to start with `<html>`
2. The snippet of code shown is not valid HTML, there is a trailing `"`.  The closing `/` is also invalid for HTML 3.2 (the only version that Java claims to understand).
3. The path is wrong.  A `File` of `C:\farmostrich.gif` (`C:\\farmostrich.gif` in a Java `String`) translates to an URI of `file:/C:/farmostrich.gif`

Note that programming is not magic.  If you put garbage in, you'll get garbage out.

Comment: 1. That was a snippet, not the entire html file, which obviously starts with html, body.
2. The actual code didn't have a trailing ". I tried /> and ></img> and neither worked.
3. The html, when read in from a file at least, doesn't need escape chars. Garbage answer in, garbage comment out.

Comment: Obvious to you maybe.  It would be obvious to me if you'd post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note that most programmers cannot write HTML to save their lives, so I'm not about to presume you are capable of it.  ..Especially not when the single line of HTML snippet posted, is wrong in 2 respects. ;)